# IE8 can't download files

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, download, internet-explorer-8

We have a windows xp machine running IE8, if it tries to download files the download either sticks @ 0% and nothing happens - no error, no progress bar - as if the download isnt starting at all.

Sometimes (on tiny files) the download will shoot to 99% then stop dead, again, no errors, no file written etc.

We have tried the following already:

- index.dat was deleted by logging off, rebooting, logging back in with
  a different user and deleting the index.dat of the user having the
  problem.
- Full IE reset – still didn’t work
- Putting an example site in Trusted Sites – still didn’t work
- Un ticking read-only on all temporary folders – still didn’t work
- Uninstalling IE8 and reverting to IE7 works in the sense that downloads work once
  again **however** re-installing IE8 afterwards just restored the
  problem and downloads are now broken again?
- Tried turning off ESET realtime protection - still didn't work

Running out of ideas - am i missing something obvious?

Comment: Can you temporarily uninstall Eset, then reset IE (again), reboot and see if there's any change?

Comment: 2 questions: 1) do other browsers download ok?; 2) when creating new Windows user does it work?

Comment: @Lizz Other browsers work fine, as i say, it works if you uninstalled IE8 and revert to IE7 - other windows accounts i'm not sure about, i'll test this on Monday (it's a remote machine that i have limited access too)

Comment: any luck w/other accounts yet?

Comment: @Lizz Apologies Lizz, forgot to come back and update this - The machine in question was on a heavily locked down wan (whitelist only) and couldn’t access Windows Updates, we put the PC on a different break-out, ran windows updates and the problems all went away - very strange! Other accounts had the same problem :)

Comment: Good to know! Can you post as an answer, and put check in checkmark to accept the answer? That would make it so we don't keep coming back to Unanswered questions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We never found the root cause for this. The machine in question was on a heavily locked down wan (whitelist only) and couldn’t access Windows Updates, we put the PC on a different break-out, ran windows updates and the problems all went away - very strange!